# How do I get top tweets for certain hashtags to my websites?

Tags: facebook, twitter

I want to make a website (my first project) that pulls the top tweets on twitter that are related to wisdom quotes and I want to put them into my website, one quote a day. I want to enable visitors to subscribe to get those quotes by email, sms, facebook updates, tweets on their accounts too. So, basically, I want to know what will I need to know to do this project. I would really appreciate any feedbacks.

Comment: what do you know already html , javascript , etc ?!

Comment: i have used html, php and know the concepts of c, cpp and oop. but not done much programming though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well somehow it's so much to do

You should read first about [twitter api](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/) , [facebook api](http://developers.facebook.com/) , email ( [it's easy one](http://www.bing.com/search?q=send%20email%20php&form=MOZSBR&pc=MOZI) ) could be done within php , sms you should find a [sms provider with api](http://www.bing.com/search?q=sms%20provider%20api&go=&qs=n&sk=&sc=5-7&form=QBRE)

For example [read this](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554756/Twitter-Search-API-Method%3a-search) for getting hashtags